# Why strcat doesn't work with pointer in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

When I execute this with a normal array it's working but with a pointer it doesn't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char source[]="Agdhefhe";
    char *accum = "";
    for(int i=0;i<=sizeof(*source)/sizeof(char);i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
            strcat(accum,source);
        }
        
    printf("%s",accum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How much space for extra characters do you think there are in the buffer pointed-to by `accum`?

Comment: Hi varkus, welcome to stackoverflow. What @adrian-mole means, I think, is that your `accum` is a pointer to a place in memory that does not have space allocated to hold the string you are accumulating. You need to `char *accum = malloc(...)`.

Comment: I think not a lot. Is there a way to do it with pointer or do i need to specify size of array ?

Comment: Oh,thanks guys for help !

Comment: What is the purpose of the loops? `sizeof(*source)` is 1 and `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition regardless of the width of a `char`.  Even without the `strcat` error, this code makes little sense.

Comment: That's a mistype. There should be ```sizeof(source)```;

Comment: @varkus : Well you should be sure to copy & paste the _exact_ code that is causing the problem, otherwise we might be unnecessarily addressing your typo.  Also  prefer `sizeof(source)/sizeof(*source)` or just `sizeof(source)`.  `sizeof(char)` is always 1.  The first form is easier in maintenance should the type of source change.

Comment: @jak : that kind of depends what the intent of the code is.  With the "correction", the loops will concatenate 45 copies of `source` (i.e. 1 + 2 + 3 + ... +9). - that may be intentional; it is unstated.  The first iteration `i = 0` does nothing.  In that case your suggestion for the size of the array is incorrect - in this case 361 bytes are required (45 x 8 + 1).

Comment: Here is a link to the description for strcat. tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm Note the comment on destination which is mentioned in the answer. Your constant of "" is not large enough to accomodate the concatenation. An error here will cause storage overlays and unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: I am not correcting anything.  That is what the OP stated in a subsequent comment.  And who is to say that that is not the intent?  After all as you point out you would otherwise use `strcpy.`  It is anyone's guess why he did not actually correct the question rather then hiding it in a comment.

Comment: You _need_ to correct the question by editing it, not just leave the error in there!  As I suggested, people will address the code in the question, not the code in your head (or even code in comments).  People like @jak will justifiably feel that they have wasted their time.

Comment: @jak : You are right insofar as the inner loop is not required - it is a triangular number series (1+2+3+4...) and can be calculated directly by `(sizeof(source) * (sizeof(source)+1)) / 2` for a single loop that iterates 45 times.  It is also possible that `strlen(source)` was intended (or `sizeof(source) - 1`, which would result in 36 copies of `source` rather then 45.  Including the NUL terminator seems an odd design decision.

Answer (score 4):

The pointer `accum` points to the  *constant* initialiser which has  length 1.  The result of both writing to the initialiser's data area and overrunning the allocated space is undefined.

`accum` must point to a writable region with sufficient space allocated to accommodate the final string.

Comment: `""` is not `const`. `const` is a type qualifier, not an adjective that means memory is read-only. Attempting to modify the arrays of string literals is not defined by the C standard due to a separate historical rule, not due to `const`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil :   I know - that is why is wrote _const_ rather then `const`.  Changing to _"constant"_

Answer (score 1):

To get it right you need to allocation enough space for the destination to write to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char source[] = "Agdhefhe";
    size_t sz = 360;
    char *accum = (char *) malloc(sz + 1);
    *accum = '\0';  // needed for first strcat call
    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(*source) / sizeof(char); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            strncat(accum, source, sz);  // strncat used to not write too much

    printf("%s", accum);
    free(accum);
    return 0;
}
```

This program writes `Agdhefhe` but can be simplified to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char const source[] = "Agdhefhe";
    size_t sz = 360;
    char *accum = (char *) malloc(sz + 1);
    *accum = '\0';  // needed for first strcat call
    strncat(accum, source, sz);

    printf("%s", accum);
    free(accum);
    return 0;
}
```

But if you wanted to duplicate the string a number of times you write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char const source[] = "Agdhefhe";
    size_t sz = 360;
    char *accum = (char *) malloc(sz + 1);
    *accum = '\0';  // needed for first strcat call
    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(source) / sizeof(char); i++)  // the change is here
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            strncat(accum, source, sz);

    printf("%s", accum);
    free(accum);
    return 0;
}
```

This writes `AgdhefheAgdhefheAgdhefheAgdhefhe...Agdhefhe` (360 characters).

Comment: 361 characters are written since the nul terminator is also written - but you have accounted for that in the code, so it is perhaps a pedantic point.  However the question is why it does not work, rather then how to make it work.  Also better perhaps to set `sz` to `((sizeof(source) * (sizeof(source)+1)) / 2) * (sizeof(source) - 1)`